# LESS: Selecting one of several parent selectors

Tags: css, nested, less

I'm almost certain there's no way to do this since I've searched a looot, but anyway hopefully...

I have this LESS code:

```
.parent-one, 
.parent-two {
     .child-of-both {color: #fff;}
     .child-of-one {color: #222;}
}
```

I want the "child-of-both" to be outputted as it is, meaning for both parents, but "child-of-one" exists only in the "parent-one" and ".parent-two" be ignored, so the output needs to be only:

```
.parent-one .child-of-one {color: #222;}
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: just write it in another line, at the end when the output is generated, it will be like that anyway

Comment: Nope, not possible in Less. In Sass there is a way to achieve something similar.

Comment: What is the CSS code that you expect? Is very strange your cuestion. The child of both is a parent with the two classes?